# Is there a way to navigate the file system more efficiently in Blender?

Tags: python, interface

I feel like I waste a lot of time clicking around trying to find files in Blender's file navigation system. Is there any way to use the python shell or some plugin for navigating the file system more easily? The "Recent" folders is helpful, but not quite fast enough...

[image: file system navigation is slow]

Comment: Navigate to the folders you use more often and click on Add Bookmark.

Comment: I don't see any difference between the Blender File Browser and the file browsing functionality of (say) the Windows Explorer. You can access the file system and blender file browser through python, but what behaviour do you wish to achieve. Maybe expand your question with an example of what is problematic and how it should behave.

Comment: I see that you don't use the Bookmark feature, but for me that's a feature that saves me a lot of time. I recommend giving it a try.

Comment: Try using maya and then tell me blender is wasting your time. I'll keep it straight blender is faster than any similar softwares you can ever find. You need to keep a good habit of managing your folder hierachy, also use bookmark, everyone use the s**t out of them.

Comment: Ok, I'll definitely invest in the bookmarks!
@Leander, in Windows Explorer I usually use ctrl+L to navigate the file system and use the autocomplete to find the folder I'm looking for quickly (i.e. when you start typing a path in the address bar of Windows Explorer, it will narrow down your options). (similar to navigating through command prompt)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the path you want, You can copy and paste it into the address bar. That'll take you straight to where you want to go!

For me, I keep all of my related files local to the blender file, as if the blender file is a main project.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to remember the exact path. But it'd be nice if I could type into the address bar and the possible folders and files in that path so far would pop up. Thanks!